Whatsapp keyboard slow during charging
I have Samsung Note 10 running Android 13. I notice that when I am charging the phone with a cable, the keyboard is slow in responding and misses characters on these two.

Typing in Whatsapp
Typing here in the Brave browser at stackexchange

Is there a rational explanation for this?  I am not looking for opinions.

Does this always happen when charging? May be the CPU is utilized because Play Store is installing updates in background. Or charging heats-up the phone so much that the CPU throttles -> use a slower charger or disable fast charging to test if this has an effect.
